# Путь к UNIX сокету не может быть более 16 символов

Tags: c++, linux, c, сокет

Есть две моих программы на C/C++. Код для работы с Unix сокетами я брал с одного давно устаревшего сайта, других более понятных примеров я не нашел. В итоге я не могу использовать сокет, длина которого более 14-16 символов. Код клиента:

```
int sock;
sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr srvr_name;
if (sock < 0) {
    perror("socket failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
srvr_name.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(srvr_name.sa_data, SOCK_NAME);
if (connect(sock, &srvr_name, sizeof (srvr_name)) < 0) {
    perror("connect failed");
    exit(2);
}
send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
```

Код сервера:

```
sock_ = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock_ < 0) {
    throw socket_exception(socket_exception::SocketError);
}
srvr_name.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
filename_c = filepath.c_str();
strcpy(srvr_name.sa_data, filename_c);
if (bind(sock_, &srvr_name, strlen(srvr_name.sa_data) +
        sizeof (srvr_name.sa_family)) < 0) {
    throw socket_exception(socket_exception::BindError);
}
listen(sock_, max_connect-1);
```

В strace(При том что путь к сокету я указал как /run/defu123456789/34567)

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/defu12345"}, 16) = -1 ENOENT
```

Размер буфера sock_name ограничен 256 байтами. Использовать библиотеку boost нельзя. Как изменить код так, что бы он работал корректно?

Comment: поле sa_data зависит от типа переменной srvr_name. Оно там может быть и 14 символов, и другое. Какое у Вас тип?

Comment: @KoVadim, Объявление `struct sockaddr srvr_name;` как на клиенте, так и на сервере. Код брался с 1 сайта.

Comment: я не знаю, с какого сайта **1** брался код,  но просто посмотрите как нужно - http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html - дело в том, что эта структура для сокетов - классический пример, как сделать полиморфизм в си без плюсов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В итоге я не могу использовать сокет, длина которого более 14-16
>   символов.

Потому, что структура *sockaddr* описана в файле */usr/include/bits/socket.h* таким образом:

```
/* Structure describing a generic socket address.  */
struct sockaddr
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.  */
    char sa_data[14];           /* Address data.  */
  };
```

Как видите, под поле адреса сокета отведено ровно 14 байт. Откуда взялось это ограничение - долгая история. Но оно есть.